# How do I get rid of the small gap beneath my bootstrap tabs?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a navbar using bootstrap, but I can't seem to get rid of the small space beneath each tab.  Can anyone help?

[image: tabs image]

Code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Baseline Assessment</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified" role="tablist">
            <li class="active"><a href="#verifyPanel" aria-controls="verifyPanel" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Step 1: Verification</a></li>
            <li><a href="#parqPanel" aria-controls="parqPanel" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Step 2: Par-Q</a></li>
            <li><a href="#exercisePanel" aria-controls="exercisePanel" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Step 3: Exercise History</a></li>
            <li><a href="#decisionPanel" aria-controls="decisionPanel" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Step 4: Decision</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Apply Padding Adjustments**

Try making the padding large enough to match your `navbar-brand` element which is explicitly making the menu larger due to it's height of `50px` :

```
.nav>li>a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    /* Adjusting this from 10px 15px to 15px should push the rows down */
    padding: 15px;
}
```

You can see an example of what this change looks like below :

[image]

**Consider Responsive Utility Classes**

You might also consider performing some type of truncation of the content of your menu items as well, as smaller resolutions will result in a "wrapping" effect. [Bootstrap's available responsive utility classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) can help mitigate this issue :

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified" role="tablist">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#verifyPanel" aria-controls="verifyPanel" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
        <span class='hidden-sm'>Step 1: Verification</span>
        <span class='visible-sm'>Verification</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <!-- Do this for each <li> element -->
</ul>
```

You can [see this in action here](http://jsbin.com/lufeyi/edit?html,output) and demonstrated below :

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, absolutely brilliant! Extremely well written and informative, people like you make this site what it is.